# View Hidden Form in checked Radio Button without onclick function (in update form)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button, laravel-8

i having a problem when i want to update form..the hidden field in selected radio button is not showing.i need to clicked another radio button and clicked back the previous radio button then it will showing the hidden field ...how i can show the hidden field  in selected radio button without onclick function(in update form).i will show my .js and html page

**.js**

```
$("#div_a_pre").hide();

$("input[name='report_type']").on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == "notification"){
        $("#div_a_pre").hide();
       
    }
    if($(this).val() == "preliminary"){
        
        $("#div_a_pre").show();
    }
    if($(this).val() == "final"){
        $("#div_a_pre").hide();
       
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="border-top form-group row">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label ">2.  Type Of Report</label>
                                <div class="col-9 col-lg-5 ">
                                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-stacked">
                                        <input type="radio" id="noti" name="report_type" value="notification" class="custom-control-input" {{ $recall->report_type == 'notification' ? 'checked' : ''}}><span class="custom-control-label">Notification / Preliminary Report</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-stacked" for="follow">
                                        <input  type="radio" id="follow" value="preliminary" name="report_type" class="custom-control-input" {{ $recall->report_type == 'preliminary' ? 'checked' : ''}}><span class="custom-control-label">Follow Up Report</span>
                                        
                                        <div class="card reveal-if-active" id="div_a_pre" >
                                            <div class="card-body">

                                                <div class="form-group row" >
                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">Report no: <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="report_no" name="report_no" class="form-control col-lg-6" value="{{$recall->report_no}}">
                                                    @error('report_no')
                                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                        </span>
                                                    @enderror
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </label>
                                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-stacked">
                                        <input type="radio" id="final" value="final" name="report_type" class="custom-control-input" {{ $recall->report_type == 'final' ? 'checked' : ''}}><span class="custom-control-label">Final Report</span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

**interface**
[There is no problem in "create form" to show hidden field  in selected radio button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83KX3.png)

[But after submit the form and want to update the form..the hidden field  in selected radio button is not showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alENI.png)